# Send data from a python page to another one

Tags: python, session, pyqt5

I have a problem regarding the sending of data, I have already done a research in this subject but I did not find my answer so I ask for your help

I am building a desktop application with pyqt5 and python, and I would like that the information entered in the form on page 1 to be transferred to page 2

I don't see how to do it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i never worked with PyQt but i can suggest for you a solution , you can use a class
with a static variable on the first page , and make a methode that can alter this variable
whenever you want , and in the other page you can import the class and get the value with a getter , for instance :

## Page 1

```
class Class1 :
  your_variable = ''

  def set_variable(self,val) :
      self.your_variable = val

  def get_variable(self) :
      return self.your_variable
```

## Page 2

```
from Page1 import Class1

varibale = Class1.getvariable()
```

Comment: thank you so much for the idea , I think this gonna work

Comment: @Elina_ch if it did you can mark my answer as useful please